# Plot legend markers with type of line

Tags: plotting, legending, plot-themes, marker

I want to put the markers symbol and the line type together in the Plotlegend.
I have used the following code

```
Data = {{{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}, {6, 4}, {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {12, 
     6}, {14, 2}, {16, 3}, {18, 4}, {20, 8}},
   {{0, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 3}, {6, 8}, {8, 2}, {10, 6}, {12, 1}, {14, 
     3}, {16, 5}, {18, 1}, {20, 2}},
   {{0, 9}, {2, 8}, {4, 4}, {6, 8}, {8, 5}, {10, 7}, {12, 1}, {14, 
     0}, {16, 0}, {18, 5}, {20, 4}},
   {{0, 3}, {2, 8}, {4, 2}, {6, 1}, {8, 2}, {10, 9}, {12, 0}, {14, 
     8}, {16, 5}, {18, 4}, {20, 7}}};
Xgrid = Range[0, 20, 1];
Ygrid = Range[0, 150, 5];
Ygrid1 = Range[0, 300, 10];
lineColors = {Blue, Red, Blue, Red};
lineWidths = {Thickness[0.003], Dashing, Thickness[0.003], 
   Thickness[0.003]};
markers1 = {Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 12], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 12], 
   Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 14], 
   Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 14]};
ListPlot[Data, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> markers1,
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800,
 PlotLabel -> Style["m", Black, 32],
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 28, Thick],
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thick, Dashed]},
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{"1", " 2", " 3", "4"},
    LabelStyle -> 22, LegendMarkers -> markers1, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 14], {Left, Bottom}]]
```

The output I am getting is

[image]

I want the plot legend to include line type in it as follows

[image]

Comment: I think you want `LineLegend` with the appropriate `LegendMarkers` setting instead. Alternatively, just `PlotLegends->Placed[{"a","b",...},...]` might already be enough

Comment: This I have tried, but it was not giving the required result.

Comment: try `LineLegend[{"1", " 2", " 3", "4"}, LabelStyle -> 22,  LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 14}, LegendMarkers -> markers1]` or `LineLegend[{"1", " 2", " 3", "4"}, LabelStyle -> 22,  LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 14}]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{{0, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}, {6, 4}, {8, 4}, {10, 3}, {12, 
     6}, {14, 2}, {16, 3}, {18, 4}, {20, 8}}, {{0, 5}, {2, 4}, {4, 
     3}, {6, 8}, {8, 2}, {10, 6}, {12, 1}, {14, 3}, {16, 5}, {18, 
     1}, {20, 2}}, {{0, 9}, {2, 8}, {4, 4}, {6, 8}, {8, 5}, {10, 
     7}, {12, 1}, {14, 0}, {16, 0}, {18, 5}, {20, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {2, 
     8}, {4, 2}, {6, 1}, {8, 2}, {10, 9}, {12, 0}, {14, 8}, {16, 
     5}, {18, 4}, {20, 7}}};
Xgrid = Range[0, 20, 1];
Ygrid = Range[0, 150, 5];
Ygrid1 = Range[0, 300, 10];
markers1 = {Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 12], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 12], 
   Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 14], 
   Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 14]};
style = {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
   Directive[Blue, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thick, Dashed]};

ListPlot[data
 , PlotStyle -> style
 , Frame -> True
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotMarkers -> markers1
 , PlotRange -> All
 , ImageSize -> 800
 , PlotLabel -> Style["m", Black, 32]
 , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 28, Thick]
 , FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[
    Style[#, 24, Bold] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}
    , LegendFunction -> "Frame"
    ], {0.85, .8}]]
```

[image]